# Is there a way I can run a c++ program through MySQL query?

Tags: c++, mysql, sql, mingw

I don't know if this is possible or not.
What I specifically want to do is:

- Run a c++ program that returns a value after some processing (perhaps using the MinGW compiler).
- Any alternatives for that level of processing.

I need it for a project and would like to know if it's even possible.

Comment: Please provide a more detailed explanation of what you are trying to do.

Comment: One way to do it would be to have a table of program executions (like scriptname | date | status), and then a c++ process actively polling this table to check for new rows (ex: status = pending) and running said script. That way you just need to insert a row to your table to run it. But I have no idea if there are better ways

Comment: @Pibben It's a university project that is a database for storing data about weather. I need to do fast and much more complex calculations that mysql can do by itself. That's why I was looking into c++ because it's fast and I know it somewhat (or atleast enough to write code for those calculations).

Answer (score 1):

Rather than executing a *program*, you could create a plugin (= a shared library) with the computation routine implemented as a *function*. You will also need to add some initialization/deinitialization routines etc, see [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/adding-udf.html) for details. It should be possible with any compiler, as the interface uses `extern "C"`, i.e. universal simple C calls.

Such a function then can be imported to MySQL using the `CREATE FUNCTION` mechanism, for instance

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION myfunc_double RETURNS REAL SONAME 'udf_example.dll';
```

According to the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-function-udf.html) of this statement, it is possible to define both simple and aggregate custom functions in this way.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems simpler than what I was planning on doing.